# How do i make my own animations within react-native-slider

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native

I have a very heavily edited version of react-native-slider that i am using to create a slider with custom images. So far i have a background image with two images acting as the thumb of the slider however i want to apply an animation 'onSlidingComplete' to one of the images.

Please note that i have edited the slider.js file within node_modules to get my desired effects and i have managed to get everything working up until now but i cannot for the life of me make any animations work.

slider declaration:

```
             <Slider

                style={styles.slider}

                trackStyle={styles.trackStyle}

                maximumValue={this.props.max}

                minimumValue={this.props.min}

                step={this.props.step}

                value={this.state.value}

                thumbTouchSize={this.props.thumbTouchSize}

                sliderBg={require('../../images/tank_bg.png')}

                thumbImage={require('../../images/thumb_slider.png')}

                thumbImageBg={require('../../images/thumb_slider_whitebg_line.png')}

                onSlidingComplete={(value) => this.onSlidingComplete(value)}

                onValueChange={(value) => this.onValueChange(value)}

                orientation={'horizontal'}

                sliderAnim={this.state.sliderAnim}

            />
```

This is how i have my slider.js set up.

the places to note that i have already tried to implement animations are the _setCurrentValueAnimated function on line 577 and the _animateSlider function on line 240.

What i am looking to do is pass a boolean into the slider through its declaration as a this.state.sliderAnim: proptypes.bool and then have the code execute a scripted animation.

All i am trying to do is make the thumbImageBg animate its height from 0 to 100% once each time onSlidingComplete is called.

Any help is appreciated a lot

```
                    `
        import React, {
          Component,
        } from "react";
        import {
          Animated,
          StyleSheet,
          Image,
          PanResponder,
          View,
          Easing,
          Dimensions,
          LayoutAnimation,
          TouchableWithoutFeedback,
          TouchableOpacity,
          Platform,
          UIManager
        } from "react-native";

        import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
        };
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

removed a lot of unnecessary code to fit 30k max char size.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
          state = {
            containerSize: {width: 0, height: 0},
            trackSize: {width: 0, height: 0},
            thumbSize: {width: 0, height: 0},
            allMeasured: false,
            value: new Animated.Value(this.props.value),
            imageBGStyle: {
              height: this.props.thumbImageBg.height,
            }
          };

          static defaultProps = {
            value: 0,
            minimumValue: 0,
            maximumValue: 1,
            step: 0,
            minimumTrackTintColor: '#3f3f3f',
            maximumTrackTintColor: '#b3b3b3',
            thumbTintColor: '#343434',
            thumbTouchSize: {width: 80, height: 80},
            debugTouchArea: true,
            animationType: 'timing',
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            sliderAnim: true,
          };

          _animateSlider() { // #################################################################
            // I USED THIS METHOD TO TRY CREATE AN ANIMATION USING LAYOUTANIMATION
            LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
            this.setState({
              imageBGStyle: {
                height: '100%',
              }
            })
            LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
            setInterval(function() {this.setState({
              imageBGStyle: {
                height: '0%',
              }
            })}.bind(this),5000)
          }

          componentWillMount() {
            this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
              onStartShouldSetPanResponder: this._handleStartShouldSetPanResponder,
              onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: this._handleMoveShouldSetPanResponder,
              onPanResponderGrant: this._handlePanResponderGrant,
              onPanResponderMove: this._handlePanResponderMove,
              onPanResponderRelease: this._handlePanResponderEnd,
              onPanResponderTerminationRequest: this._handlePanResponderRequestEnd,
              onPanResponderTerminate: this._handlePanResponderEnd,
            });

            if(this.sliderAnim == true)
            {
              this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(100);
              alert('sliderAnim is true and runs');
              console.log('sliderAnim is true and runs');
            }
          };

          componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            var newValue = nextProps.value;

            if (this.props.value !== newValue) {
              if (this.props.animateTransitions) {
                this._setCurrentValueAnimated(newValue);
              }
              else {
                this._setCurrentValue(newValue);
              }
            }
          };

          render() {
            var {
              minimumValue,
              maximumValue,
              minimumTrackTintColor,
              maximumTrackTintColor,
              thumbTintColor,
              thumbImage,
              styles,
              style,
              trackStyle,
              thumbStyle,
              debugTouchArea,
              orientation,
              sliderBg,
              thumbImageBg,
              sliderAnim,
              ...other
            } = this.props;
            var {value, containerSize, trackSize, thumbSize, allMeasured} = this.state;
            var mainStyles = styles || defaultStyles;
            var outputRange;
            if (orientation === 'horizontal') {
              outputRange = [0, containerSize.width - thumbSize.width];
            } else {
              outputRange = [containerSize.height - thumbSize.height, 0];
            }
            var thumbStart = value.interpolate({
                inputRange: [minimumValue, maximumValue],
                outputRange: outputRange,
                //extrapolate: 'clamp',
              });
            var valueVisibleStyle = {};
            if (!allMeasured) {
              valueVisibleStyle.opacity = 0;
            }

            var minimumTrackStyle = {
              position: 'absolute',
              // width: Animated.add(thumbStart, thumbSize.width/2),
              backgroundColor: minimumTrackTintColor,
              ...valueVisibleStyle
            };

            if (orientation === 'horizontal') {
              minimumTrackStyle.width = Animated.add(thumbStart, thumbSize.width / 2);
              minimumTrackStyle.marginTop = -trackSize.height;
            } else {
              minimumTrackStyle.marginLeft = -trackSize.width;
              minimumTrackStyle.top = thumbStart;
              minimumTrackStyle.height = Animated.add(thumbStart, -trackSize.height);
              minimumTrackStyle.height = Animated.multiply(minimumTrackStyle.height, -1);
            }

            var touchOverflowStyle = this._getTouchOverflowStyle();

            let imageBGStyle = [defaultStyles.thumbImgStyleBg, this.state.imageBGStyle];

            return (
              <View {...other} style={[mainStyles.container, style]} onLayout={this._measureContainer}>
                <Image style={defaultStyles.trackImgStyle} source={this.props.sliderBg}>
                  <View
                    style={[{backgroundColor: maximumTrackTintColor,}, mainStyles.track, trackStyle]}
                    renderToHardwareTextureAndroid={true}
                    onLayout={this._measureTrack} />

                    {/*LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);*/}

                  {/*<Animated.View
                    renderToHardwareTextureAndroid={true}
                    style={[mainStyles.track, trackStyle, minimumTrackStyle]} >
                    </Animated.View>*/}

                    {/*<TouchableOpacity
                      style={[defaultStyles.touchArea, {zIndex: 100}]}
                      onPress={this.animateSlider.bind(this)}>*/}

                  <Animated.View
                    onLayout={this._measureThumb}
                    renderToHardwareTextureAndroid={true}
                    style={[

                      mainStyles.thumb, thumbStyle,
                      {
                        transform: [
                          { translateX: thumbStart },
                          { translateY: 0 }
                        ],
                        ...valueVisibleStyle
                      }
                    ]} 
                  >


                      <Animated.Image 
                      style={imageBGStyle} 
                      source={this.props.thumbImageBg} >
                        <Animated.Image 
                        style={defaultStyles.thumbImgStyle} 
                        source={this.props.thumbImage}/>
                      </Animated.Image>
                  </Animated.View>
                    {/*</TouchableOpacity>*/}


                  <View
                    renderToHardwareTextureAndroid={true}
                    style={[defaultStyles.touchArea, touchOverflowStyle]}
                    {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
                    {debugTouchArea == true && this._renderDebugThumbTouchRect(thumbStart)}
                  </View>
                </Image>
              </View>
            );
          };

          _animate() { 
            Animated.timing(this.animatedValue,
            {
              toValue: 50,
              duration: 5000,
              easing: Easing.bounce
            }).start()
          };

          _getPropsForComponentUpdate(props) {
            var {
              value,
              onValueChange,
              onSlidingStart,
              onSlidingComplete,
              style,
              trackStyle,
              thumbStyle,
              ...otherProps,
            } = props;

            return otherProps;
          };

          _handleStartShouldSetPanResponder = (e: Object, /*gestureState: Object*/): boolean => {
            // Should we become active when the user presses down on the thumb?
            return this._thumbHitTest(e);
          };

          _handleMoveShouldSetPanResponder(/*e: Object, gestureState: Object*/): boolean {
            // Should we become active when the user moves a touch over the thumb?
            return false;
          };

          _handlePanResponderGrant = (/*e: Object, gestureState: Object*/) => {
            this._previousStart = this._getThumbStart(this._getCurrentValue());
            this._fireChangeEvent('onSlidingStart');
          };
          _handlePanResponderMove = (e: Object, gestureState: Object) => {
            if (this.props.disabled) {
              return;
            }

            this._setCurrentValue(this._getValue(gestureState));
            this._fireChangeEvent('onValueChange');
          };
          _handlePanResponderRequestEnd(e: Object, gestureState: Object) {
            // Should we allow another component to take over this pan?
            return false;
          };
          _handlePanResponderEnd = (e: Object, gestureState: Object) => {
            if (this.props.disabled) {
              return;
            }


            console.log("holy fuck");

            this._setCurrentValue(this._getValue(gestureState));
            this._fireChangeEvent('onSlidingComplete');
            if(this.sliderAnim === true)
            {
              this._animateSlider();
            }
          };

          onSlidingComplete() {
            alert("nah this works!");
          }

          _measureContainer = (x: Object) => {
            this._handleMeasure('containerSize', x);
          };

          _measureTrack = (x: Object) => {
            this._handleMeasure('trackSize', x);
          };

          _measureThumb = (x: Object) => {
            this._handleMeasure('thumbSize', x);
          };

          _handleMeasure = (name: string, x: Object) => {
            var {width, height} = x.nativeEvent.layout;
            var size = {width: width, height: height};

            var storeName = `_${name}`;
            var currentSize = this[storeName];
            if (currentSize && width === currentSize.width && height === currentSize.height) {
              return;
            }
            this[storeName] = size;

            if (this._containerSize && this._trackSize && this._thumbSize) {
              this.setState({
                containerSize: this._containerSize,
                trackSize: this._trackSize,
                thumbSize: this._thumbSize,
                allMeasured: true,
              })
            }
          };

          _getRatio = (value: number) => {
            return (value - this.props.minimumValue) / (this.props.maximumValue - this.props.minimumValue);
          };

          _getThumbStart = (value: number) => {
            var ratio = this._getRatio(value);

            var start = 0;

            if (this.props.orientation === 'horizontal') {
              var length = this.state.containerSize.width - this.state.thumbSize.width;
              start = ratio * length;
            } else {
              var length = this.state.containerSize.height - this.state.thumbSize.height;
              start = length - (ratio * length);
            }

            return start;
          };

          _getValue = (gestureState: Object) => {
            var length = 0;

            if (this.props.orientation === 'horizontal') {
              length = this.state.containerSize.width - this.state.thumbSize.width;
            } else {
              length = this.state.containerSize.height - this.state.thumbSize.height;
            }

            var thumbStart = this._previousStart;

            var ratio;
            /*
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                THE NEXT STATEMENT IS EDITED TO AUTOMATICALLY TAKE ROTATED INPUTS FROM THE USER. EDIT IF "ORIENTATION" WORKS!

              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            */
            if (this.props.orientation === 'horizontal') {
              thumbStart += -gestureState.dy;
              ratio = (thumbStart / length);
            } else {
              thumbStart += gestureState.dy;
              ratio = 1 - (thumbStart / length);
            }

            if (this.props.step) {
              return Math.max(this.props.minimumValue,
                Math.min(this.props.maximumValue,
                  this.props.minimumValue + Math.round(ratio * (this.props.maximumValue - this.props.minimumValue) / this.props.step) * this.props.step
                )
              );
            } else {
              return Math.max(this.props.minimumValue,
                Math.min(this.props.maximumValue,
                  ratio * (this.props.maximumValue - this.props.minimumValue) + this.props.minimumValue
                )
              );
            }
          };

          _getCurrentValue = () => {
            return this.state.value.__getValue();
          };

          _setCurrentValue = (value: Number) => {
            this.state.value.setValue(value);
          };

          _setCurrentValueAnimated = (value: Number) => {
            var animationType   = this.props.animationType;
            var animationConfig = Object.assign(
                  {},
                  DEFAULT_ANIMATION_CONFIGS[animationType],
                  this.props.animationConfig,
                  {toValue : value}
                );
                // #######################################################################################################################
                // I CHANGED THIS THIS.STATE IN THE NEXT LINE SO THAT IT WOULD CHANGE THE HEIGHT OF MY IMAGES STYLE IN AN ANIMATION BUT IT DID NOT WORK
            Animated[animationType](this.state.imageBGStyle.height, animationConfig).start();
          };

          _fireChangeEvent = (event) => {
            if (this.props[event]) {
              this.props[event](this._getCurrentValue());
            }
          };

          _getTouchOverflowSize = () => {
            var state = this.state;
            var props = this.props;

            var size = {};
            if (state.allMeasured === true) {

              if (props.orientation === 'horizontal') {
                size.width = Math.max(0, props.thumbTouchSize.width - state.thumbSize.width);
                size.height = Math.max(0, props.thumbTouchSize.height - state.containerSize.height);
              } else {
                size.width = Math.max(0, props.thumbTouchSize.width - state.containerSize.width);
                size.height = Math.max(0, props.thumbTouchSize.height - state.thumbSize.height);
              }
            }

            return size;
          };

          _getTouchOverflowStyle = () => {
            var {width, height} = this._getTouchOverflowSize();

            var touchOverflowStyle = {};
            if (width !== undefined && height !== undefined) {
              var verticalMargin = -height / 2;
              touchOverflowStyle.marginTop = verticalMargin;
              touchOverflowStyle.marginBottom = verticalMargin;

              var horizontalMargin = -width / 2;
              touchOverflowStyle.marginLeft = horizontalMargin;
              touchOverflowStyle.marginRight = horizontalMargin;
            }

            if (this.props.debugTouchArea === true) {
              touchOverflowStyle.backgroundColor = 'orange';
              touchOverflowStyle.opacity = 0.5;
            }

            return touchOverflowStyle;
          };

          _thumbHitTest = (e: Object) => {
            var nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
            var thumbTouchRect = this._getThumbTouchRect();

            return thumbTouchRect.containsPoint(nativeEvent.locationX, nativeEvent.locationY);
          };

          _getThumbTouchRect = () => {
            var state = this.state;
            var props = this.props;
            var touchOverflowSize = this._getTouchOverflowSize();

            var rect = new Rect(
              0,
              0,
              props.thumbTouchSize.width,
              state.containerSize.height
            );

            if (this.props.orientation === 'horizontal') {
              rect.x = touchOverflowSize.width / 2 + this._getThumbStart(this._getCurrentValue()) + (state.thumbSize.width - props.thumbTouchSize.width) / 2;
              rect.y = touchOverflowSize.height / 2 + (state.containerSize.height - props.thumbTouchSize.height) / 2;
            } else {
              rect.x = touchOverflowSize.width / 2 + (state.containerSize.width - props.thumbTouchSize.width) / 2;
              rect.y = touchOverflowSize.height / 2 + this._getThumbStart(this._getCurrentValue()) + (state.thumbSize.height - props.thumbTouchSize.height) / 2;
            }

            return rect;
          };

          _renderDebugThumbTouchRect = (thumbStart) => {
            var thumbTouchRect = this._getThumbTouchRect();

            var positionStyle = {
              left: thumbTouchRect.x,
              top: thumbTouchRect.y,
              width: thumbTouchRect.width,
              height: thumbTouchRect.height,
              flex: 1,
              flexDirection: 'column',
              justifyContent: 'center'
            };

            if (this.props.orientation === 'horizontal') {
              positionStyle.left = thumbStart;
            } else {
              positionStyle.top = thumbStart;
            }
            return (
              <Animated.View
                style={[defaultStyles.debugThumbTouchArea, positionStyle]}
                pointerEvents='none'
              />
            );
          };

          _renderThumbImage = () => {
            var {thumbImage} = this.props;

            if (!thumbImage) return; 


            return {thumbImage};
          };
        };


        var defaultStyles = StyleSheet.create({
          container: {
            // height: 440,
            justifyContent: 'center',

          },
          track: {
            height: TRACK_SIZE,
            borderRadius: TRACK_SIZE / 2,

          },
          thumb: {
            position: 'absolute',
            width: THUMB_SIZE,
            height: '100%',
            borderRadius: THUMB_SIZE / 2,

          },
          thumbImgStyle: {
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            backgroundColor:'transparent'
          },
          thumbImgStyleBg: {
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            backgroundColor:'transparent'
          },
          trackImgStyle: {
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            flex: 1,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
          },
          touchArea: {
            position: 'absolute',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            top: '-40%',
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: '-40%',
          },
          debugThumbTouchArea: {
            position: 'absolute',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            opacity: 0.5,

          }
        });`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer,

I ended up using a LayoutAnimation with a custom animation passed in but the issues i were having were not to do with animation at all but with how it handles this.setState(). I just used setState and then used a setTimeout() to make sure that the state was updated when the animation ran, as i had it i was animating from 100% to 100% and it was giving me no animation at all because it would then set the width to 0% and not animate back to 100% as it was still 100% during the animation and not 0%. I am new enough to react native to not have understood why but my guess is that it has to do with this.setState running much later then my animation code and thus having no effect.

Ill make sure i have more clarity in my future questions as this was too vague to help with.